# authorization error when accessing an aspx page

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2008, authorization, sharepoint-2007

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2003 R2 Enterprise. I am developing using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5 + IIS 6.0.

I have put a simple aspx page into layout folder (the code is very simple, just redirect to another page, and I write inline script code in asp.net), here is my code, and I met with unauthorized error (403) when I select to browse the page from IIS 6.0 manager.

I am not in Active Directory or Windows domain environment. I have enabled permission to anonymous users for the whole SharePoint site. Any ideas what is wrong?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>

<script runat="server" type="text/C#">
protected void Page_Load(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
}
</script>
<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the Windows security permissions are set appropriately for the folder where your Web page is stored. The IIS user for the AppPool (most likely the default, but may not be) will need to have read rights to this folder.

Comment: I want to check by default, to access aspx pages by anonymous users in layout folder, there should not be any authorization issues?

Comment: Find out the user identity under which the AppPool is running, then make sure they have appropriate permissions.